# How to loop through External JSON file data circularly using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, json

Hi i am trying to show JSON file data circularly using Javascript one by one. But i am not able to do it. I am able to show all the data at a time and even one just first data using Javascript Slice function.

How can i loop circularly and can show one data at a time.Please find my code below. Right now this code limiting the showing data to 1, if i remove that slice function i can see whole data.

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
//jobs('experiment','assets/js/job.json'); 
$('.announce-section').addClass('zoom');
$.getJSON("assets/js/job.json", function( result ){
    $('#wrapper header').html(result.title);
    $('#wrapper h2').html(result.subtitle);
        var rlength = result.jobs.length;
        alert(rlength);
        $.each(result.jobs.slice(0,1), function(key, field){
            var jlength = result.jobs.length;
            var img = field.image;
            $('.pattren').append('<div class="data screen'+key+'"></div>');
            if(img !='')
                {
                    $('.pattren .data').append('<img src="assets/img/'+field.image+'" />');
                }
        $('.pattren .data').append('<ul><li>'+field.label_1+'<span>'+field.description_1+'</span></li><li>'+field.label_2+'<span>'+field.description_2+'</span></li><li>'+field.label_3+'<span>'+field.description_3+'</span></li><li>'+field.label_4+'<span>'+field.description_4+'</span></li></ul>');
        });
});
});
```

Comment: you mean to format and display json as html?

Comment: You might want to post a fiddle

Comment: yeah i am already formatting into html. What i am asking is i have 4 Employees of data. I want to show each Employee data at a time with slight delay. Now i am able to show all the data without using slice function. I am also able to show only first employee data using slice function. But how i can show one employee data then next employee like that when i reached last employee. I want to show again first employee then continous operation

Comment: Nick Karnik I have lot of resources to post into Fiddle

Comment: I like to know how to put delay in between to each calls while parsing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two ways:

1. Only one div and change fields placed in the container, like image, description etc.
2. Generate div containers by data, if four employees then four div, and slide circularly.

Comment: i am trying first one, i am trying to replace the data every time. How can i put delay between two replacements

Comment: Create a field to store all data, and a temp field to store current index. index++, index--; index = 5 = 5 % 4 = 1;

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41083/discussion-between-teddy-and-venkat)

Comment: bro please come to chat